# How to display a push notification for android in status bar using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I want to implement push notification in android using phonegap and i used th ebelow link to implement GCM

https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

I am able to implement push notification and i am able to get a small sample text on my mobile screen after submitting the appid regid and sender id but i want to display the notification in status bar. Can anyone please help me how to display a push notification in status bar using above example.

Comment: You say you got it working already, so edit the source code. where you receive the message show a notification.

Comment: @Klaasvaak yah but what to write for show notification

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Cordova StatusBarNotification plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification)
 or if you want a faster solution, you could simply add the following native Java code into your GCMIntentService.java onMessage() function:

```
String message = extras.getString("message");
String title = extras.getString("title");
Notification notif = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, message, System.currentTimeMillis() );
notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestSampleApp.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notif);
```

and dont forget to add following imports,

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
```

Be sure to replace **YourActivityClassName.class** with the name of your stub class that extends **DroidGap**. For instance, in the sample project it is called **MainActivity**.